# Python get URL contents when page requires JavaScript enabled

Tags: javascript, python, html, http, text

I am looking to get the contents of a text file hosted on my website using Python. The server requires JavaScript to be enabled on your browser. Therefore when I run:

```
    import urllib2  
    target_url = "http://09hannd.me/ai/request.txt"
    data = urllib2.urlopen(target_url)
```

I receive a html page saying to enable JavaScript.
I was wondering if there was a way of faking having JS enabled or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`Selenium` is the way to go here, but there is another "hacky" option.

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26393257/2517622

```
import requests

url = 'http://09hannd.me/ai/request.txt'
response = requests.get(url, cookies={'__test': '2501c0bc9fd535a3dc831e57dc8b1eb0'})
print(response.content) # Output: find me a cafe nearby
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative for urllib that supports `JavaScript` [HTML Session with JavaScript Support (render)](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) .

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

custom_session = HTMLSession()
```

```
r = custom_session.get('http://python-requests.org')

r.html.render() #Run JavaScript

print(r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')['months'])
```

---

```
'<time>25</time>'
```