# Python: Can't extract element from website with bs4

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract an element from this [site](https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/ontario/mississauga). More specifically, I am trying to extract the temperature.

This is the following element I am attempting to extract using BeautifulSoup4:

```
<p class="temperature">-1<span>°C</span></p>
```

The following is my python code that is supposed to extract the element from the mentioned site:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/ontario/mississauga')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'lxml')
 
print(soup.find_all('p', {'class':'temperature'}))
```

And it just returns an empty array.

```
[]
```

I would be really appreciative if anyone could help me with this.

*Note: I am new to python*

Comment: The detail you want is loaded via javascript so python-requests is not enough. It's coming out as empty because it **is** empty. What you're doing is web scraping. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393231/using-python-requests-with-javascript-pages

Comment: I see. So what library do you recommend I use to extract the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as @RobinAnupol mentioned, you have several options depending on how similar you want to be to a real browser.

1. Open the website manually on a browser and observe the api calls the site does with javascript code. Replicate them using requests in python
2. Use a javascript rendering engine like [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash)
3. Use [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) with a real browser (there drivers for chrome, ie, firefox, phantomjs etc)

Comment: I just tested it out with selenium, and it works just like planned, it is lower compared to requests, however that could be because the text I am trying to extract is in javascript and not in HTML.

Comment: That's great. If you want accept this answer so that the question doesn't appear as unanswered