# Can't find values in table using BeautifulSoup (python)

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've been using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')

tables = soup.find_all('table')
```

but it just gives me dummy text like "Lorem Ipsum..."

I can see the text I want to scrape when I inspect the element, but I cannot see it when I press "View Page Source".

Does this mean this code is Javascript driven? If so, how do I get around this without a driver?

Here is the URL  to the site:
https://rocketreach.co/Doordash-email-format_3205573

Here is some of the code when I inspect the element (table is highlighted):
[image]

Comment: can you provide an url? Also, please don't post pictures of html. Use the snippet tool via [edit] so we can use for testing.

Comment: having the url would be helpful.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393231/using-python-requests-with-javascript-pages