# How to bypass JavaScript detection when using requests in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, python-requests, browser-automation

So there is a problem with JavaScript and requests (in Python) and that is, it does not use JavaScript when requesting a webpage.

The website I'm working with (https://access.paylocity.com/) requires JavaScript and without it, it changes the content of the page to just a text at the top saying, "Please enable JavaScript to view the page content."

(I could be wrong here but) I think one solution is the use of Selenium, but that would replace requests which I'm fine with as long as there are no other ways of fixing/bypassing this JavaScript detection.

(For those wondering, this python project of mine is supposed to automatically fetch the events on the Paylocity calendar, then port those events to another calendar that I frequently use everyday. It's also just intended for myself.)

Edit: Here is the code I have if that will help https://pastecode.io/s/GXTUO1BgtR (I didn't know where to paste my code, so I decided on that website. If I should change it, please comment or say something about it.)

Comment: If js is required, then there is probaly a API where the data came from. Dump the approch of using the UI and try to talk directly to the API.

Comment: @Marc Yes, that's ultimately what I want to do (due to speed differences). I know Paylocity has an API, but a preexisting python module would be more practical in my opinion. ICloud has an API (but a simple search can tell you that there are python modules that allow you to interact with iCloud which is what I want).

Answer (score 1):

Since the website you're working with is dynamically loading the JS as far I can tell, I think you have no other choice as to making use of Selenium. I had a project on my own a couple weeks ago and run into a similar problem which I could also solve using Selenium. But, I'm no expert, I'm just giving away my thoughts on this.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I have not selected this as the answer (since you are no expert and are just giving your thoughts away, and because there is only one answer), but I do respect that you did give an answer because ultimately, one answer is better than none. If nothing else, I will probably get into using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54056631/6056034
This worked for me!

```
Python
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://www.yourjspage.com')
r.html.render()  # this call executes the js in the page
```