# Can't parse full webpage, using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, request, urllib

Parsing page of QA service sli.do:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

voting_url = "https://app.sli.do/event/i6jqiqxm/live/questions"
voting_page = urllib.request.urlopen(voting_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(voting_page, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())

for link in soup.find_all('span'):
    print(link.get('Linkify'))
```

`print(soup.prettify())` returns html-document, but there is no content with tag `span` `class="Linkify"`, which contains text of questions. It could be found in Chrome: https://app.sli.do/event/i6jqiqxm/live/questions

Comment: Have you inspected the contents of `voting_page`? The element you're seeking is generated via JavaScript. Neither `request` nor `bs4` is capable of interpreting or otherwise executing JavaScript. As such, this question is a duplicate of [Using python Requests with javascript pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393231/using-python-requests-with-javascript-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the api as the data is generated dynamically. You might need to figure out the access_token part if that also changes dynamically.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
auth = s.post('https://app.sli.do/api/v0.5/events/8ca635b0-e80e-47be-b506-cb131dbbed4c/auth').json()
access_token = auth['access_token']

url = 'https://app.sli.do/api/v0.5/events/8ca635b0-e80e-47be-b506-cb131dbbed4c/questions'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
'authorization': 'Bearer %s' %access_token}
payload = {
'path': '/questions',
'eventSectionId': '4145620',
'sort': 'top',
'highlighted_first': 'true',
'limit': '9999'}

jsonData= s.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()


for each in jsonData:
    print(each['text'])
```

**Output:**

```
Can I ask a question anonymously?
How many participants does Slido support?
Do participants need an account to join?
Can I download the list of questions  from my Q&A?
Can the moderators control what questions are seen?
How do you pronounce Slido?
Is it possible to change the colors of Slido so that they match our branding? 
What tools does Slido integrate with?
Is it easy to ask a question? 
Can i send a link to participants prior to event?
Can participants submit questions at any time?
Is there a profanity control for the text of the questions? 
Is there an option to have a name required?
Is Slido free to use?
Is Slido good for a regular meeting q&a with the CEO where you can ask questions anonymously in advance?
how do i upload slido into my powerpoint presentation?
Can everyone see each other's questions?
```

Comment: Hey @chitown88 just for knowledge from xhr you find this urls?? can you share how did you find

Comment: @BhavyaParikh, yes. That's exactly where I found it

Comment: @chitown88 where did you find this part: 8ca635b0-e80e-47be-b506-cb131dbbed4c ?

Comment: @BhavyaParikh also in XHR

Comment: you mean Crome developer tools?

Comment: Yes. Network -> XHR found in the dev tools