# scrape text with BeautifulSoup not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the text from the minutes published in the webpage of the central bank of Brazil:

https://www.bcb.gov.br/publicacoes/atascopom

Have tried to use BeautifulSoup as per the code below, but only get empty results

```
url = "https://www.bcb.gov.br/publicacoes/atascopom"
html_text = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.find_all('p', class_='paragrafo'))
```

After doing a lot of research, it seems the problem has to do with the JavaScript, but I do not know how to fix it (new to Python). The same code works fine when **scraping** similar text from other central bank webpages.

Anyone has any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the website uses JavaScript to render the content. Requests library doesn't have JavaScript support. You can try using `selenium` or `requests_html` for this purpose. More details [can be found in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393231/using-python-requests-with-javascript-pages)

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, that site provides RSS-feeds here https://www.bcb.gov.br/acessoinformacao/rss and there is the `Atas do Copom` feed.

Following is possible method to start with

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bcb.gov.br/api/feed/sitebcb/sitefeeds/atascopom"
html_text = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.content, 'xml')
print(soup.find_all('content'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from external URL in Json format. You can use next example how to load it:

```py
import requests
import textwrap
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bcb.gov.br/api/servico/sitebcb/atascopom/principal?filtro="

data = requests.get(url).json()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data["conteudo"][0]["OutrasInformacoes"], "html.parser")
print("\n".join(textwrap.wrap(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))))
print()
print("PDF:", data["conteudo"][0]["Url"])
```

Prints:

```
A) Atualização da conjuntura econômica e do cenário básico do Copom 1
1. No cenário externo, estímulos fiscais e monetários em alguns países
desenvolvidos promovem uma recuperação robusta da atividade econômica.
Devido à presença de ociosidade, a comunicação dos principais bancos
centrais sugere que os estímulos monetários terão longa duração.
Contudo, a incerteza segue elevada e uma nova rodada de
questionamentos dos mercados a respeito dos riscos inflacionários
nessas economias pode tornar o ambiente desafiador para países
emergentes. 2. Em relação à atividade econômica brasileira, apesar da
intensidade da segunda onda da pandemia, os indicadores recentes
continuam mostrando evolução mais positiva do que o esperado,
implicando revisões relevantes nas projeções de crescimento. Os riscos
para a recuperação econômica reduziram-se significativamente. 3. As

...

a evolução recente e as perspectivas para a economia brasileira e para
a economia internacional, no contexto do regime de política monetária,
cujo objetivo é atingir as metas fixadas pelo Conselho Monetário
Nacional para a inflação.

PDF: /content/copom/atascopom/Copom239-not20210616239.pdf
```