# Webscrape Magento 1 and bypass javascript check with python requests

Tags: python, magento, python-requests

I have a small project to webscrape prices from some stores using requests and beautiful soup.

One of these stores is now checking for javascript enable browser. I have found that it uses Magento 1.

I have tried the requests-html library, but it did not work.

I know that I can use selenium and headeless-chrome. I have tested it and works fine.

But as long as I run the project on the cloud, it would be much easier and less expensive to use requestes.

On stackoverflow there is a post where one solution was suggested: send the request with the cookied that is set by a website when it checks for javascript enable.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66917621

Has anyone tried this solution on Magento 1?

I suspect that the data that I need to scrape is not generated by javascript on the page, but the check for javascript enable browser does not allow the page to load.

Comment: Any chance you could share the URL to the store?

Comment: I think that I have found the cookie: sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_xxxxxxxx