# How to get html contents after scripts

Tags: python, html

I would like to use the beautiful soup html parser to get specific information from a [website](https://www.umimeinformatiku.cz/skakacka-opravdova-vyzva/58). To get the content of the website I used the .content function from the requests module. The problem is that the website has scripts in front of the data I need. Therefore, the .content function returns only the code before the scripts. How could I work my way around this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.umimeinformatiku.cz/skakacka-opravdova-vyzva/58")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("td"))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393231/using-python-requests-with-javascript-pages you will find what you are looking for here