# Python Web Crawler No Results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I am making a basic Web Crawler/Spider with Python. I am trying to crawl through a YouTube channel and print all the titles of the videos on it but it **never** returns anything.

Here is my code so far:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/c/DanTDM/videos'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

x = soup.select(".yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer")

print(x)
```

And the output is always: `[]`. An empty list (which means it didn't find anything). I need to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems correct.

Call `print(response.text)` and see if YouTube is returning you a blocking page.

Anti scraping measures can be in action, as checking your user agent, etc.

Comment: yeah, could also be that some javascript is running client side that isnt being picked up. See related question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393231/using-python-requests-with-javascript-pages

Comment: No no, I see what's happening. My response was HTML, of course and it was the 'Before you continue to YouTube' page. I would need to use Selenium and WebDriver to automate it and then maybe run the other code or make a different Web Crawler using Selenium.

Comment: Yes, with "blocking page" I meant also a dialog with dynamic content. No wonder why YouTube made the dialog that way ...

Answer (score 1):

## **Browser Automation with Selenium**

When I send a request to YouTube, I receive the following page:

(A 'Before you continue to
Youtube' page).

[image]

So...

We should use Selenium instead as we need to click one of the buttons. I don't **think** we can interact with the website using the requests module.

Selenium allows you to have control over your browser. Read the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/)!