# How do you scrape integer values using python and beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning web scraping using Beautiful Soup and Python. I thought a good first step would be to simply extract the temperature from a website. I have followed a tutorial which taught me to access text from a job posting website. However, while trying to extract the temperature from the weather network website I cannot return the temperature value to the console.

Here is my code,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.theweathernetwork.com/us/weather/new-york/new-york'
data = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
temp = soup.find('span', class_ = "temp").text

print(temp)
```

when I add the ".text" to the temp variable the code complete but the print is blank.
when I remove the ".text" from the temp variable I get the desired spot in the HTML code but without the integer, like this `<span class="temp"></span>`

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and got the same results as you.

You can see that the reason you're not getting anything is because there is nothing to get.

If you run:

```
with open('output.html','w',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Open the file (output.html) and view the page source. You will see that there is actually nothing in the `<span class="temp">` section.

This means that those values are only populated at runtime i.e. likely using javascript.

In order to overcome this, you can use some JS render library such as [selenium](https://medium.com/@jb.ranchana/web-scraping-with-selenium-in-python-amazon-search-result-part-1-f09c88090932) or [requests_html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393231/using-python-requests-with-javascript-pages). I am not at my desktop at the moment so I can't run it for you and give you the exact code but this is the most common way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the value in the span DOM element is computed using a Javascript async call to a third-party API. BeautifulSoup downloads the html response prematurely, so that data is not captured.